# How to set value from another table to new column in table

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables Brand and Product with one-many relationship.

I want to add a column name Quantity in Brand table for sum product same brand. (All table have data exists)

How i do that, thank you my bad English

Comment: Why do you need a column with the count that you then have to maintain (e.g. update it every time a product is added, removed, or updated to point at a different brand)? This is redundant information because you can always retrieve it in real time without having to resort to triggers or some background process to keep the aggregate in sync.

Comment: Instead of adding a new column, you can do this when you query the tables: `SELECT brand.*, prod.count_of_product FROM brand LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT brand_id, count(*) as count_of_product FROM product GROUP BY brand) prod ON brand.id = prod.brand_id;`. IF you add this as a new column, the second you INSERT or DELETE into `product` then your static count in the new column is incorrect. If you want to preserve this sql you can create a view in your database with this SQL and then when you need to see product counts by brand, query the view directly.

Comment: I'm doing an exercise with Trigger. The problem requires me to create a new column for the Brand table and calculate the total product for each Brand.

Comment: @VietNguyen as other people have pointed out, this is not the correct use of Triggers or Columns. If you want to see the Brand and Product Quantity then you can simply create a new view on these two tables. If you add a column to store the count, then you will be violating the db normalisation form rules, not the best practice actually possibly the worst thing you can do to your db design.